# Transitioning from Pointer to object?

Tags: c++

Here is a quick snippet of code from my program (taken out of context but should be fine for the question)

```
Card::Card(int value, char suit)
{
    value = value;
    suit = suit;
}

Card cards[52];

Card c = new Card(RANKS[i],SUITS[j]);
cards[size] = c;
```

Here I get an error because new Card(x,y) returns a pointer to a card so it should be

```
Card* c = new Card(RANKS[i],SUITS[j]);
```

What do I do if I want to end up with just a card object? I was under the impression that I could do this using the address operator and do something like
    cards[size] = &c;

However the compiler doesn't seem to like this. Can anyone help me? Should be fairly straightforward, unfortunately I'm a little rusty with my C/C++.

Thanks!

Comment: `value = value; suit = suit;` I don't know if this is in your real code, but if so it means you're not setting your class data members `value` or `suit` correctly here. You either need different names, or you should write `this->value = value; this->suit = suit;` Alternatively you could use the constructor initializer list: `Card::Card(int value, char suit) : value(value), suit(suit) {}`. (The rules for the initializer list make sure data members are not confused with parameters.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do I do if I want to end up with just a card object?

Use:

```
int cardIndex = <some card index>
cards[cardIndex] = Card(RANKS[i],SUITS[j]);;
```

Comment: @k9b Forget Java when using C++, try minimizing using `new`